# How does Apache Jena sort strings that have unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, sparql, jena

I have a query in Apache Jena that sorts by a string. The sorting part looks like `ORDER BY ASC(?title)`. `?title` is a Unicode string, it may be Chinese, french, Russian etc.

I am having a JavaScript application where this data is fetched via an API. So I request for example the first 10 records with an offset of 10 (would return page 2) it would return certain results. When the application is in offline mode I would like to use the exact same sorting algorithm so I can make sure the end user sees the same items.

So my question:
How does Apache Jena sort strings that have Unicode characters?

Reason for asking:
In the JavaScript side I would like to implement the exact same sorting algorithm.

I have found a little trick for now.

By using `ENCODE_FOR_URI` inside the Sparql query and `encodeURIComponent` in the JavaScript I have consistent sorting. It is not really correct but it helps with getting better results.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is explained in the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOrderBy - for Unicode chars, the unicode codepoint is used. You can see examples in the table of the section I linked to